# Create single{custom}.php with data in table out of wp_posts

Tags: customization, single, table

I have a table named "doors" out of the wordpress structure. It comes from a csv and i need to make a single-doors.php in which i'll show the data from the requested door.

My question is.. How ? The table "doors" has 4 fields: ID, Name, Description, Type.

Any help would be appreciated on this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a theme is to display your WordPress data. And a plugin is to modify WordPress functionality. What you are trying to do is both. You want to create a new table (which is something to do with a plugin), and then display that data (a theme).

So, you have to do the following in my opinion.

A. Create a plugin to add a table to the database, and populate table content as well

B. Create your theme files to display that content

As far as the plugin goes, you should probably create the db table when you activate your custom plugin, and if you want to be sophisticated, maybe add a UI to allow you to add data whenever that data becomes available, such as file upload, or something like that.

Once you are happy with this part, create a custom theme file, that allows you to read the content of your "doors" table and display it in any way you like.

Another approach to your theme is to create a child theme that only has the additional functionality you seek (for doors). This way, your theme is somehow independent of the actual changes. Meaning, if you change your original theme, your can just change the reference of your child theme and it should work.

A third approach to your theme is to make the specific custom theme pages within your plugin and have it contained in one location. This approach bends the rules because you are designing a theme page within a plugin.

After all, it is up to you. Those are the ideas I can come up with. Good luck.

Comment: We're digging a bit deeper. We have the data on our tables and have a plugin/theme mix all setup and working apart from these items. Ok the user access mysite.com/doors/wooden-door. What happens from here on? How can i know that the user is requesting wooden-door from the doors table?

Comment: You use your URL path as query parameters. You said it, in the URL, you have `mysite.com/doors/wooden-door`, so your custom query would look for 'doors' and 'wooden-doors'. You should do that via custom queries in your custom theme page.